# Database normalization: Using separate tables to store a single field

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

Currently our database is set up so that a payment transactions records a payment type ID, and this links to a payment type (cash, check, credit) table that contains these values. Example:

> **Payment Transaction:**
>
> - ID
> - Amount
> - Date
> - Payment Type ID
>
> **Payment Type:**
>
> - ID
> - Payment Type (Cash, Credit)

My question is whether or not I should just remove the payment type table, and just store the payment type value as text inside the payment transaction.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148694/should-i-create-a-new-table-into-my-database-for-this). except with payment types it's pretty certain that no new information will ever need to be add data per payment type. 'Cash' doesn't link to anything, there's nothing I need to know about Cash itself, it just is.

As far as I can tell the pros and cons would of replacing the payment type table with a single field would be:

**Pros**

- Removes a mostly unnecessary join whenever the payment type needs to be found.
- The payment type for a transaction will always accurately reflect what it was at the time the transaction was recorded. i.e. If I change the 'Cash' record in the payment types table to 'Credit' (for whatever reason), all payment transactions that link to Cash will now be linked to Credit.

**Cons**

- Storing the payment type as a text field will slow down sorting by payment type, and make such a sort somewhat messier than it is now.
- The payment type for a transaction will always accurately reflect what it was at the time the transaction was recorded. i.e. If I had a typo and the payment type was stored as 'Kash', I could easily fix that typo and all transactions that link to that payment type will automatically be updated.

I'm leaning towards removing the payment type table and adding the single field to the payment transaction table, what do you recommend would be the best course of action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with either of your pro arguments.

> Removes a mostly unnecessary join whenever the payment type needs to
>   be found.

There's just your assumption that this will be a performance bottleneck.  Denormalization is something you should do when you have data that says you must.  This isn't one of those times.

> The payment type for a transaction will always accurately reflect what
>   it was at the time the transaction was recorded. i.e. If I change the
>   'Cash' record in the payment types table to 'Credit' (for whatever
>   reason), all payment transactions that link to Cash will now be linked
>   to Credit.

You should not allow someone to modify the payment type this way.  Changing the payment type should be another transaction, with its own timestamp.

Any relational database can handle the JOIN and the normalized tables.  You're guilty of premature optimization, I fear.

I'd spend less time worrying about this and more time thinking about how you'll deal with history.  How long will you keep transactions around before moving them out to a history table?  Have you thought about partitioning your database by months according to timestamp?  That would be more worthy of your efforts.

Comment: I'm really talking more specifically about the benefits they offer the developer/my lazy self. I know the JOIN will have little if any impact of performance, but it's much nicer to write out a query without that JOIN if possible. Same for changing the payment types, the user doesn't have the ability to do so, but it's fairly common for us to have to rearrange the payment types. Rather than relying on varying IDs I think it's much better suited to rely on a static 'Cash' or 'Credit', as the text value won't ever be changing much.

Comment: No benefit that I can see.  I don't agree that it's nicer.  I would argue against it, but it's your schema.

Comment: I think I'll just leave things the way they are then. It really is a pain having to change half the application whenever a payment type gets changed, but I'd much rather be keeping up with best practices. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, I would recommend a payment type change as a separate transaction with its own timestamp.  Like you said, you want to preserve what the payment type was on the day the original was made and when the change happened.  You don't get that with an UPDATE, unless you have a trigger to record it.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the PaymentType table, you replace a foreign key check with a table CHECK constraint:

```
PaymentType   CHAR(6) NOT NULL CHECK(PaymentType IN('Cash', 'Credit', 'Cheque')
```

OK — you write 'cheque' as 'check'; just another difference between English and American.

Now, this makes it much more difficult to find out what the possible values are; you have to analyze the system catalog to find out.  With the separate table, you can examine the separate table to find out what's allowed.  Suppose you start tracking 'Debit' separately from 'Credit'; you add a row to a table, vs a table schema change.  Suppose you decide you need to record which codes are allowed in future transactions (so 'Cash' ceases to be an option).  You can add a column to the Payment Type table to indicate that this code is no longer valid; it is much harder to do that with a simple CHECK constraint.

So, even though you currently have limited or no extra data in the Payment Type table, I would use the Payment Type table rather than embedding the payment type in the Payment Transaction table.

Were it my design, though, I'd probably use a CHAR(1) or CHAR(2) code as the identifier for the payment type, rather than a numeric column.  Granted, all three types start with 'C', so maybe you'd use 'A' for cAsh, 'H' for cHeck, and 'R' for cRedit (and maybe 'D' or 'E' for Debit or dEbit) with a CHAR(1) code; with CHAR(2), you'd use 'CA', 'CH', 'CR' (and maybe 'DE').  The full name can be stored in the payment type table for use in reports.  In this case, the benefits are not huge, but saving 4 bytes per record on enough records (a large enough number of small enough records) and it can become a factor in your storage costs.  Of course, index overhead also comes into play; if the column in the Payment Transaction table must be indexed, then the smaller field uses less index space.